# Unable to edit WFS layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver

I am unable to edit WFS layers in QGIS. I have set up a service access rule in Geoserver to allow users associated with role "staff_edit" to edit WFS layers. I followed [this tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/sysadmin/security/multiuser/index.html) to ensure that I did not miss a critical step. I am currently using QGIS 2.16 and Geoserver 2.9.0.

I have the following service rule in place:

```
wfs.*   GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN,staff_edit
```

No other rules have been specified (yet). I am able to connect to the server and add WFS and WMS layers in QGIS, but I am unable to edit WFS layers. The following have been verified:

- WFS service level set to "Complete"
- "staff_edit" role given WRITE access mode
- The data come from a PostGIS data store and credentials grant editing privileges (currently using admin credentials).
- tried uploading a vector dataset that was not in PostGIS, and same inability to edit.

How can I allow a specified role to edit WFS layers in QGIS?

**UPDATE: The problem only exists on QGIS 2.16.3. Editing works on QGIS 2.14.**

Comment: Check the GeoServer logs, do you get any error when trying to commit a change? What about in QGIS own logs?

Comment: No errors in either log when loading WFS layers in version 1.1.0 or 2.0.0. Also note update above. This problem only exists in QGIS version 2.16.

Comment: > In the "Modify W**F**S Connection" dialog, leaving Version as
> "auto-detect", "1.1.0", or "2.0.0" will not allow WFS editing. Only by
> selecting 1.0.0 will the user be able to edit a WFS layer in QGIS
> 2.16. Thanks for the tip! Still the case with Qgis 2.18, thx for pointing to this small detail...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and "solved" it by choosing wfs version 1.0.0 in QGIS.

It (1.0.0) seems to not be the default WFS version in QGIS 2.16 but it is in older versions.

Comment: This works, though I believe the moderators would like to see more detailed answers in the future. In the "Modify WMS Connection" dialog, leaving Version as "auto-detect", "1.1.0", or "2.0.0" will not allow WFS editing. Only by selecting 1.0.0 will the user be able to edit a WFS layer in QGIS 2.16. Thanks for the tip!